# Close and/or kill mysqli connection at the end of the php script?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, kill

Do I need to explicitly kill and/or close a mysqli connection at the end of a script.  At the moment, I do neither, and it works, but I don't have much load.

I've heard that there is connection pooling, and mysqli connections are re-used...  do I need to close the connection then at all?

Answer (score 2):

You should always close your connections at the end of the main script. If you uses some php5 and object to handle your DB just think about using `__destruct()` to automatically close it

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Answer (score 0):

No it is not necessary to close a mysql connection at the end of a script. PHP does it automatically.

Comment: it doesn't cost much to close it, and you're sure it is :) i experienced some problems with that on php4, and i never forget to close them now !

Comment: Not really. For example if you close a connection but later open it again its not so good.

Comment: You could close the connection with auto_append_file but nobody does this I think.

Answer (score 0):

it is not necessary but generally that's good practice. I personally, when wish to boost error-checking mechanism, you $con->close() for almost each function. e.g:

```
if($stmt = $db->prepare($statment))
{
    if($db->bind_param($str, $param1, $param2))
    {
        // the rest of the code and error checking
    }
    else
    }
       $db->close();
    }
}
else
{ 
 $db->close();
}
```

This makes OOP necessary. Since you can simply write function doing this automatically with many other security checks added. codeIgniter as a framework has nice DB connectors whith superb security at a basic general level.